# java.io.IOException in Generating Signed APK

Tags: android-studio, release, android-proguard

I am trying to use  'Proguard' in my application. App will Build perfect in AVD and run,but When i trying to release my app in android studio,I am getting IOException Exception that show in below:

```
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.NavigationView { void setNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout { void setOnLayoutChangeListener(android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout$OnLayoutChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout$OnLayoutChangeListener'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout { void setOnAttachStateChangeListener(android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout$OnAttachStateChangeListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout$OnAttachStateChangeListener'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout { void setOnTabSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$OnTabSelectedListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$OnTabSelectedListener'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView { void setInAppPurchaseListener(com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseListener'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView { void setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView { void setAdListener(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView { void setAdListener(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView { void setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView { void setInAppPurchaseListener(com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseListener'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView { void setInAppPurchaseListener(com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseListener'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView { void setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView { void setAdListener(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView { void setAdListener(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView { void setAdSizes(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize[]); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView { void setAppEventListener(com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.AppEventListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.AppEventListener'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView { void setCorrelator(com.google.android.gms.ads.Correlator); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.Correlator'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView { void setOnCustomRenderedAdLoadedListener(com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.OnCustomRenderedAdLoadedListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.OnCustomRenderedAdLoadedListener'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.NativeAdView { void setNativeAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.NativeAd); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.NativeAd'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.search.SearchAdView { void setAdListener(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.search.SearchAdView { void setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.flags.impl.FlagProviderImpl { void init(com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzd); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzd'
    Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton { void setOnPlusOneClickListener(com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton$OnPlusOneClickListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton$OnPlusOneClickListener'
    Note: there were 3 references to unknown classes.
    You should check your configuration for typos.
    (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
    Note: there were 23 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
    You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
    (using '-keep').
    (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
    Note: there were 12 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
    You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
    (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
    Warning:there were 127 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
    You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
    If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
    the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
    (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
    Warning:there were 48 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
    You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
    be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
    (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)
    Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
    > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

And this is the gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

        packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ir.onlinegpstracker.iranavl.onlinegpstracker"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
        }

    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/jtds-1.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/http-core-4.1.jar')


    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,there is no error on codes.so need ignore by adding these codes in proguard-rules.pro

```
-dontwarn android.support.design.**
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-dontnote com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-dontnote android.support.v4.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-dontnote android.support.v7.**
```

And now it will work without any problem.
Thanks.